# Transaction Required Exception in JPA Spring Hibernate App

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, transactions

I saw many posts in this forum regarding the Transaction required Exception. But none of them resolved the issue. 
My question is:
In my scenerio, my application is working perfectly for some functionality and some throws Exception.

what kind of situation the `entityManager.flush()` throws Transaction Required Exception in Spring+Hibernate+JPA?

Comment: You mean your function sometimes works well while sometimes not? or 1 function works well while another not?

Answer (score 0):

try to put `@Transactional` at the method level

Comment: The method which is marked as '@Transactional' in my side. any other reason??